# Unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error while using GridSearchCV for KNN hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, data-science, css-grid, knn, hyperparameters

So I was tuning the n_neighbors hyper parameter using the following code after importing all the necessary libraries

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

    df = pd.read_csv('path of file')
    df.head()

    # Creating feature "X" and target "y"
    X = df.drop('Species', axis=1).values
    y = df['Species'].values

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

    #This is where the error pops up

    param_grid = {'n_neighbors', np.arange(1,50)}

    #.................................................

    knn_cv = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid, cv=5)
    knn_cv.fit(X,y)
    Print ('Best parameters: {}'.format{knn_cv.best_params_})
    Print ('Best score: {}'.format{knn_cv.best_score_})


   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-94-75a644fe3635> in <module>
          1 knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
    ----> 2 param_grid = {'n_neighbors', np.arange(1,50)}

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

While executing an error saying Unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' pops up. Please help. I'm a beginner trying to practice some supervised learning on the iris dataset.

Comment: Hi @Mrigank, welcome to SO. Can you please post a more meaningful snippet of your code, including the stack trace, so we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Hey @Tgsmith61591, thank you for letting me know about that. Forgive me, I've just started and still figuring out how to use StackOverflow in the best way possible. Here is the snippet of my code with the stack trace as you mentioned.